# Syntax/Grammar check during program writing

Tags: syntax, grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Learning incremental compilation design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995264/learning-incremental-compilation-design)

As a undergraduate project, we design a simple scrip language, and translate the scrip codes to c++ with gcc for the execution on MS os. We would like to implement a function of *syntax/grammar check* when user writing the scrip code, but have no idea of how to do. Is the check function dependent/independent of the IDE? Does there exist open-source implementation so that we can learn from them? We know the syntax highlighting from [Writing a syntax highlighter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809423/writing-a-syntax-highlighter), and is it related to the check function?

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An article entitled as "Learning incremental compilation design" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995264/learning-incremental-compilation-design) contributes how to realize this feature. It also provides a technical report (in PDF) to this topic.